# PHP soapCall generates unwanted htmlEntities

Tags: php, xml, soap-client, webservice-client, html-entities

My PHP code tries to communicate with a Web Service.

I want to send: `<ns1:in0><![CDATA[<node>`

But PHP sends: `<ns1:in0>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;node&gt;`

If I send the `<-version` request in SoapUI, it works fine.

If I send the `&lt;-version`  request in SoapUI, it returns error.

My code (without private info):

```
    <?php
    $wsdl_path='https://....wsdl';
    $ws_path='https://...';
    $var='<![CDATA[<node>
             <subnode1>
             ...
             </subnoden>            
             </node>]]>';
    $methodName='methodName';

    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl_path,array('location'=>$ws_path,'trace'=>true,'exceptions'=>false));
    $result = $soapClient->__soapCall($methodName,array(array("in0"=>($var))));

    echo "RESULT:\n";
    var_dump($result);
    echo "\n************************\n";
    echo "REQUEST:\n" . $soapClient->__getLastRequest();
    echo "\n************************\n";
    echo "REQUEST HEADERS:\n" . $soapClient->__getLastRequestHeaders();
    echo "\n************************\n";
    echo "RESPONSE:\n" . $soapClient->__getLastResponse();
    echo "\n************************\n";
    echo "RESPONSE HEADERS:\n" . $soapClient->__getLastResponseHeaders();
    echo "\n************************\n";
    ?>
```

My code runs:

```
RESULT:
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["out"]=>
  NULL
}

************************
REQUEST:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://..."><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:methodName><ns1:in0>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;node&gt;
         &lt;subnode1&gt;
         ...
         &lt;/subnoden&gt;            
         &lt;/node&gt;]]&gt;</ns1:in0></ns1:methodName></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope> 

************************
REQUEST HEADERS:
POST ... HTTP/1.1
Host: ...
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.4.25
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 783


************************
RESPONSE:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body><methodNameResponse xmlns="http://..."><out xmlns="http://..." xsi:nil="true"></out></methodNameResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope> 
************************
RESPONSE HEADERS:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: ...
Server: Apache/2.2.15  HP-UX_Apache-based_Web_Server (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.8o
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.4 JSP/2.0
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8

************************
```

Someone can tell me how to send the request without html entities?

Thanks

More info:

I can not use NuSOAP

I tried:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl_path,array('location'=>$ws_path,'trace'=>true,'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT,'exceptions'=>false));
$params = new SoapVar($var, XSD_ANYXML);
$result = $soapClient->$methodName(array($params));
```

But it wasn't a solution.

Comment: why do you cant to send a CDATA section within the request as the data should be automatically encoded by the SoapClient and PHP?

Comment: why do you want to send a CDATA section within the request as the data should be automatically encoded by the SoapClient and PHP?

Comment: I removed CDATA, that was the solution.
Thanks a lot, Mikaël

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I send request without CDATA (i.e. `<ns1:in0>&lt;node&gt;`) and it works fine.